# Pane recuperado do arquivo fxml vêm nulo

Tags: javafx

Estou tentando recuperar um Pane do arquivo fxml para um controller, com a finalidade de adicionar ações em seus componentes. Estou usando a notação @FXML para trazer esse painel para a classe, porém ele vêm com valor nulo.

Controller modelo:

```
package views.controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public abstract class ControllerView implements Initializable {

@FXML
protected Pane painelInicial;

protected Pane painelAtual = painelInicial;

public void alternarPainel(Pane novoPainel){
    if(painelAtual != null){
        painelAtual.setVisible(false);
    }

    painelAtual = novoPainel;
    painelAtual.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Controller que manipula o painel que faz a chamada para o painel nulo:

```
package views.controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class ControllerPainelOpcoesVenda extends ControllerView {

@FXML
private Button botaoCadastrarVenda;

@FXML
private Pane painelCadastroVenda;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    botaoCadastrarVenda.setOnAction(event->{
        alternarPainel(painelCadastroVenda);
    });
}
}
```

Arquivo FXML do painel nulo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane fx:id="painelCadastroVenda" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="850.0" styleClass="painel" visible="false" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="labelTituloCadastroVenda" layoutX="248.0" layoutY="24.0" styleClass="titulo" text="CADASTRO DE VENDA" />
        <TableView fx:id="tabelaListaProdutos" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="90.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="588.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colunaProduto" prefWidth="312.0" text="PRODUTO" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colunaQuantidade" prefWidth="118.0" text="QUANTIDADE" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colunaPrecoTotal" prefWidth="177.0" text="PREÇO TOTAL" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
        <Button fx:id="botaoAdicionarProduto" layoutX="680.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="117.0" styleClass="botoes-padrao" text="ADICIONAR PRODUTO" wrapText="true" />
        <Pane fx:id="painelBotoesFormularioVenda" layoutY="429.0" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="850.0" style="-fx-background-color: gray;">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="botaoSalvarCadastroProduto1" layoutX="686.0" layoutY="12.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" styleClass="botoes-padrao" text="SALVAR" />
                <Button fx:id="botaoVoltarCadastroProduto1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="12.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="botoes-padrao" text="VOLTAR" />
            </children>
        </Pane>
        <Button fx:id="botaoRemoverProduto" layoutX="680.0" layoutY="272.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="117.0" styleClass="botoes-padrao" text="REMOVER PRODUTO" wrapText="true" />
        <Label fx:id="labelTotalVenda" layoutX="437.0" layoutY="391.0" style="-fx-font-size: 20px; -fx-text-fill: gray;" text="TOTAL" />
        <Label fx:id="labelValorTotalVenda" layoutX="541.0" layoutY="391.0" style="-fx-font-size: 20px; -fx-text-fill: #4caf50;" text="0,00" />
    </children>
</Pane>
```

Painel que o controller manipula:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane fx:id="painelOpcoesVenda" layoutY="100.0" maxHeight="480.0" maxWidth="850.0" minHeight="480.0" minWidth="850.0" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="850.0" styleClass="painel" visible="false" fx:controller="views.controllers.ControllerPainelOpcoesVenda" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="botaoCadastrarVenda" layoutX="230.0" layoutY="72.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="117.0" styleClass="botoes-crud" text="NOVA VENDA" wrapText="true" />
        <Button fx:id="botaoRemoverVenda" layoutX="507.0" layoutY="72.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="117.0" styleClass="botoes-crud" text="REMOVER VENDA" wrapText="true" />
        <Button fx:id="botaoAtualizarVenda" layoutX="230.0" layoutY="288.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="117.0" styleClass="botoes-crud" text="ATUALIZAR VENDA" wrapText="true" />
        <Button fx:id="botaoVisualizarVenda" layoutX="507.0" layoutY="288.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="117.0" styleClass="botoes-crud" text="VISUALIZAR VENDA" wrapText="true" />
    </children>
</Pane>
```

Painel principal FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane fx:id="janelaPrincipal" maxHeight="580.0" maxWidth="850.0" minHeight="580.0" minWidth="850.0" prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="850.0" styleClass="painel" stylesheets="@../css/estilo.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="views.controllers.ControllerPainelMenu">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="painelMenu" maxHeight="100.0" maxWidth="850.0" minHeight="100.0" minWidth="850.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="850.0" style="-fx-background-color: gray;">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="botaoClientes" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="224.0" styleClass="botoes-padrao" text="CLIENTES" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#0a0d0b7d" />
            <Button fx:id="botaoProdutos" layoutX="313.0" layoutY="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="224.0" styleClass="botoes-padrao" text="PRODUTOS" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#0d0101" />
            <Button fx:id="botaoVendas" layoutX="612.0" layoutY="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="224.0" styleClass="botoes-padrao" text="VENDAS" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#170202" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Pane fx:id="painelInicial" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="850.0" style="-fx-background-color: gray;" styleClass="painel">
         <children>
            <PieChart fx:id="graficoDeEstatisticas" layoutX="175.0" layoutY="40.0" title="ESTATISTICAS" />
         </children></Pane>
      <fx:include fx:id="painelOpcoesCliente" source="PainelOpcoesCliente.fxml" />
      <fx:include fx:id="painelOpcoesProduto" source="PainelOpcoesProduto.fxml" />
      <fx:include fx:id="painelOpcoesVenda" source="PainelOpcoesVenda.fxml" />
      <fx:include fx:id="painelCadastroCliente" source="PainelCadastroCliente.fxml" /> 
      <fx:include fx:id="painelCadastroProduto" source="PainelCadastroProduto.fxml" />
      <fx:include fx:id="painelCadastroVenda" source="painelCadastroVenda.fxml" />      
   </children>  
</Pane>
```

Main:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

private Stage palco;
private Pane painelPrincipal;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    this.palco = primaryStage;
    iniciarJanelaPrincipal();       
}

private void iniciarJanelaPrincipal() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("views/fxml/JanelaPrincipal.fxml"));
        painelPrincipal = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(painelPrincipal);
        palco.setScene(scene);
        palco.setResizable(false);
        palco.show();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch();
}
}
```

Erro que acontece quando clico no botao cadastrarVenda:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at views.controllers.ControllerView.alternarPainel(ControllerView.java:20)
>           at views.controllers.ControllerPainelOpcoesCliente.lambda$0(ControllerPainelOpcoesCliente.java:31)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
>           at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1):

O FXML do seu painel nulo não possui um controlador, representado pela tag: `fx:controller`, logo você deve atribuir ou criar um controller para seu Pane. Usando seu próprio código como exemplo, o controller do seu painel deve ficar parecido com isto:

```
fx:controller="views.controllers.ControllerPainelMenu
```